# Cannot send new build to testers from expired TestFlight app

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an issue with TestFlight: I let the expiry date passed by (60 days) and just uploaded a new build. I added all testers to it, but it didn’t notify of new update.

- my testers can’t open the old testflight build on device to trigger an update, because it says it expired.
- my testers can’t download from the initial email invite because it says app already accepted.
- And when opening TestFlight, my app is missing and does not give my testers the opportunity to update.

Therefore, how do send a new build to testers for an app that expired?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to notify your testers once you upload a new version on Itunes. With the new mail build mail, testers can download app.

Comment: try to add new build with new build number so your tester will get a new build , if it is not so check itunes you have to add missing compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your **internal testers** and invite them again. An email would be generated on internal testers ID's  and have to accept it. Then enter  **redeem code** into the TestFlight App.